# How to copy from csv to postgres with Go?

Tags: postgresql, csv, go

I want copy my large csv-file to Postgres. Schema `create table doe(firstname text, lastname text, phone text);`

CSV-file

`Firstname|LastName|Phone
John|Doe|55-55-555
Jane|Doe|66-66-666`

Go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := "psql"
    args := fmt.Sprintf("-U postgres -d test -c \"\\copy doe from '%s' delimiter '|' csv header;\"", os.Args[1])
    if err := exec.Command(cmd, args).Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    println("Ok")
}
```

And now a have error

> ./copy /tmp/test.csv panic: exit status 2
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.main()    /tmp/copy.go:21 +0x16b

What I do wrong? If run in console

> psql -U postgres -d test -c "\copy doe from '/tmp/test.csv' delimiter '|' csv header;"
>
> COPY 2

Comment: To figure out the error, instead of `Run`, use [`Cmd.CombinedOutput`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput), then printout/observe the combined-output message.

Comment: args should be a slice of strings with each arg in its own entry. I have to wonder - why write a Go app that just forks out to psql? Just write a bash script, or if you're doing it in Go, do it in Go using psql driver.

Comment: Also your pasted error is not from your pasted source; the error references line 21 which doesn't exist in your sample source, making this difficult for anyone else to reason about.

Comment: @Adrian because psql driver too slow.  Thanks, replace args to slice solved error.

Answer (score -1):

```
func main() {
    cmd := "psql"
    args := []string{"-U", "postgres", "-d", "test", "-c", fmt.Sprintf(`\copy doe from '%s' delimiter '|' csv header;`, os.Args[1])}
    v, err := exec.Command(cmd, args...).CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        panic(string(v))
    }
    println("Ok")
}
```